# Span of vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $
a=(1,1,0,0),
b=(0,1,1,0),
c=(0,0,1,1),
d=(1,0,0,1)\in\mathbb{R}^4$.

Give a basis $\mathbf{B}$ for the intersection of the two linear spaces spanned by $a,b$ and $c,d$.

Can anyone help me with this.I dont understand the question at all.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it is you don't understand the question? Is it that you don't understand some of the words in it (if so, which ones?), or that you understand what the question is asking but have no ideas on how to approach it?

Comment: I understood the question,but i do not have a proper idea about how to solve it.I am new to this FunctionalAnalysis subject so i am trying to improve my basic skills.

Comment: Can you please suggest me any good books for fucntionalanalysis.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

Let $x\in span(a,b)\cap span(c,d)$ then 
$$x=\alpha a+\beta b=\gamma c+\delta d$$
so
$$x=(\alpha,\alpha+\beta,\beta,0)=(\delta,0,\gamma,\gamma+\delta)$$
solve this system and find $x$

Comment: I am learning a swift way so +1

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

You may also walk a longer way as follows:

1. Suppose that $W=\langle a,b\rangle,~~~V=\langle c,d\rangle$.
2. Find the dimensions of both subspaces $\text{dim}(W),\text{dim}(V)$ by examining the number of non zero rows of the echelon form of two proper matrices established by $a,b$ and $c,d$.
3. Find the number of non zero rows of a matrix established by $a,b,c,d$ all together to find the dimension of $V+W$.
4. Use the well-known identity $\text{dim}(V\cap W)=\text{dim}{W}+\text{dim}(V)-\text{dim}(V+W)$

Comment: @Congratulations 40000+

Comment: @AdiDani: Thanks Adi, my dear friend :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, to start with, you need to figure out what the space spanned by $a,b$ is, and you need to figure out what the space spanned by $c,d$ is. Then, you need to find their intersection. Once you've done that, finding a basis should be easy.

Do you know how to do each of these things? If not, please let me know which ones you're unfamiliar with.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I know how to get span for R3 but i am not familiar with R4.Can you please help me.

Comment: Well, for example, the subspace spanned by $a,b$ is the set of all linear combinations of $a$ and $b$-that is the set of all vectors of the form $$\begin{align}\alpha a+\beta b &= \alpha(1,1,0,0)+\beta(0,1,1,0)\\ &= (\alpha,\alpha,0,0)+(0,\beta,\beta,0)\\ &=(\alpha,\alpha+\beta,\beta,0),\end{align}$$ where $\alpha,\beta$ are some real numbers. Put another way, it is the set of vectors $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\Bbb R^4$ such that $x_4=0$ and $x_2=x_1+x_3.$

Comment: Do you see how this is the same sort if thing as what we were doing in $\Bbb R^3,$ and why these descriptions mean the same thing? Can you figure out the space spanned by $c$ and $d$? The intersection of the two spaces?